# DevTools Chromium --remote-debugging-port

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, devtools

Can i use two instances of Chrome or Edge(Chromium) with different ports at same time, the same browser with distincts --profile-directory?

Example (shortcut Windows):

**--remote-debugging-port=9222** and **--remote-debugging-port=9223**

When i open the first browser with port 9222 is ok for list on inspect, but at second browser no.

Comment: Looking at this [list of chrome flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) I see one called `--remote-debugging-targets` which is described as _"Porvides a list of addresses to discover DevTools remote debugging targets. The format is <host>:<port>,...,<host>:port."_  _Might_ be worth an investigation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download debug version of chrome from the [website](https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/)and install it

2. in your terminal：(the app location maybe different, you can open the app in your finder to examine it)

```html
/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Dev.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Dev --remote-debugging-port=9222
```